# Is there a definition of cylinder that these equations satisfy

Tags: surfaces

Our teacher is claiming that (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) the following surfaces are "cylinders":

- $3x+y+\frac{7}{2}=0$
- $y=x^2$
- $z^2 = y$
- $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$

Is there any definition of cylinder that can justify this statement, and if so, which definition?

The last one is the only one that fits the definition that I know (which he calls an "elliptic cylinder")

Comment: Only the last might possibly qualify as a cylinder (in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the $z$ coordinate unbounded, so more an infinite pipe than a cylinder) in any usage I am aware of.

Comment: Take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28602/a-cylinder-is-not-always-can-shaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When most people heat the word "cylinder" they are thinking of a "right circular cylinder" -- that is --  a circle which is copied up and down along a line perpendicular to the plane that circle lies in.

The term "cylinder" can more generally refer to a curve copied along any line. So for example,
$y=x^2$ is a parabola in the plane, but since there is no reference to $z$, the parabola $y=x^2$ and $z=5$ also satisfies this equation (same for $z=$any constant). So in 3-space, the graph of $y=x^2$ is a parabola copied up and down the $z$-axis. Instead of a circular (regular old) cylinder, you have a "parabolic cylinder".

If you notice, all of the equations you have listed above only list 2 out of the 3 variables (x,y,z). So the graphs of these surfaces are graphs of a curve copied along the remain variable's axis.

For example: Here is (part of) the graph of $z^2=y$ (another parabolic cylinder)...

[image]

Notice that the parabola $z^2=y$ (in the $yz$-plane) has been copied along the $x$-axis.

[Wikipedia Page on Cylinders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29) -- see "other types of cylinders"

Comment: Is a plane considered to be a cylinder?

Comment: In this general sense, yes, a plane is a cylinder since it's a line copied up and down along another line.